# Tone JS - Transport.stop(); does not work with scheduled events

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, tone.js

I am using Tone JS for a project and I am using [Transport.scheduleOnce](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.39/Transport#scheduleOnce) to schedule events with the [Sampler](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r12/Sampler). Here is what I have so far, also here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wopmx2ng/1/) of it (you may need to click run a couple times to hear the audio come through when fiddle initially loads)

My code:

```
const sound = 'https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3';
let samplerBuffer;

const sampler = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   samplerBuffer = new Tone.Sampler(
    { 
      A1: sound
    },
    {
      onload: () => {
        resolve()
      }}
  ).toMaster();
})


sampler.then(() => {
  Tone.Transport.scheduleOnce(() => {
    samplerBuffer.triggerAttack(`A1`, `0:0`)
  });

  Tone.Transport.start();
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Now should be stopping');
    Tone.Transport.stop();
  },1000)
})
```

I am trying to stop the audio from playing after 1 second using the `Transport.stop()` method however it does not seem to work. I think I have followed the docs as I should so where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tone.Transport` is triggering your sample.
What you want to do is either use the `Tone.Player` if you only want to play sounds like a "jukebox".

If you really need a sampler, then should to look into [Envelopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(music)) because the Sampler uses one.

In short: The `Tone.Transport` like the maestro in a concert. `Transport` is only setting the time (only the BPM not the playback speed). `Tone.Transport.start()` will trigger all registered instruments (in your case the Sampler) to start doing whatever you programmed them to do. If you want to stop the Sampler from playing in this mode. You can do `samplerBuffer.releaseAll()`

```
const sound = 'https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3';
let samplerBuffer;

const sampler = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   samplerBuffer = new Tone.Sampler(
    { 
      A1: sound
    },
    {
      onload: () => {
        resolve()
      }}
  ).toMaster();
})


sampler.then(() => {
  Tone.Transport.scheduleOnce(() => {
    samplerBuffer.triggerAttack(`A1`, `0:0`)
  });

  Tone.Transport.start();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Now should be stopping');
    samplerBuffer.releaseAll();
    // samplerBuffer.disconnect();
  },1000)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9zns7jym/6/